# Entropy condition for balance law of Burgers type

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

I am studying the wellposedness of the Burgers equation with initial data:

\begin{align}\label{eq:BP}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u + u \partial_x u = 0, & t >0, \quad x \in\mathbb{R}, \\
u(0,x) = u_0(x), & x \in \mathbb{R}, 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The definition of the classic entropy condition for the initial value problem of this equation says that this due satisfies the following two assumptions:

- (Integral equation)
  $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(u \varphi_{t}+\frac{u^{2}}{2} \varphi_{x}\right) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{~d} t+\left.\int_{0}^{\infty} u_{0} \varphi \mathrm{d} x\right|_{t=0}=0
  $$
  for all test function.
- (Entropy condition)
  $$
  u(x+z, t)-u(x, t) \leqslant C\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right) z
  $$
  for some $C\geq 0$ and almost all $x,\,z\in \mathbb{R}^+,\, t>0$.

However, if now I consider
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u + u \partial_x u = G(u), & t >0, \quad x \in\mathbb{R}, \\
u(0,x) = u_0(x), & x \in \mathbb{R}, 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
**How can I define the entropy condition in this case ?
Is it the same that the case before?
Why?**

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point may be chapter 5 of [Dafermos' book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-04048-1), where I quote from the abstract:

> It will be shown that when the system of balance laws is endowed with a companion
> balance law induced by a convex entropy, the initial value problem is locally
> well-posed in the context of classical solutions: sufficiently smooth initial data generate
> a classical solution defined on a maximal time interval, typically of finite duration.
> However, in the presence of damping induced by relaxation or other dissipative
> mechanisms, and when the initial data are sufficiently small, the classical solution
> exists globally in time. Classical solutions are unique and depend continuously on
> their initial values, not only within the class of classical solutions but even within
> the broader class of weak solutions that satisfy the companion balance law as an
> inequality admissibility constraint.

This deals with classical solutions first. Later weak solutions are also discussed. You can read on companion balance laws in Chapter 1.4, 1.5 of the aforementioned book.